# How to run python-daemon with twisted

Tags: python, twisted, daemon

I am trying to run a daemon process using python-daemon library. I am also using twisted for networking.

The server is pretty simple:

```
class Echoer(pb.Root):
    def remote_echo(self, st):
        print 'echoing:', st
        return st

if __name__ == '__main__':
    serverfactory = pb.PBServerFactory(Echoer())
    reactor.listenTCP(8789, serverfactory)
    reactor.run()
```

And the client which is also supposed to be the daemon process follows as:

```
class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.stdin_path = '/dev/null'
        self.stdout_path = '/dev/tty'
        self.stderr_path = '/dev/null'
        self.pidfile_path =  '/tmp/foo.pid'
        self.pidfile_timeout = 5

    def run(self):
        clientfactory = pb.PBClientFactory()
        reactor.connectTCP("localhost", 8789, clientfactory)
        d = clientfactory.getRootObject()
        d.addCallback(self.send_msg)
        reactor.run()

    def send_msg(self, result):
        d = result.callRemote("echo", "hello network")
        d.addCallback(self.get_msg)

    def get_msg(self, result):
        print "server echoed: ", result

app = App()
daemon_runner = runner.DaemonRunner(app)
daemon_runner.do_action()
```

When I run the client as `python test.py start` the daemon process is started but somehow the connection is not established.

But if I changed the last lines in the client as below:

```
app = App()
app.run()
```

Then the connection would be correctly established and working. But in this case it is not a daemon process anymore.

What am I missing here? How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

Twisted has daemonizing capabilities built-in already, so you don't need to add `python-daemon`. There may be some funny behavior overlaps between the two that may be biting you. As you've seen, once you've gotten your application it's pretty easy to run in the foreground as you've done above. It's also pretty easy to run it as a daemon; see the [`twistd` description](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/basics.html) and [`twistd` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/twistd) for more info on `twistd`, but basically you're just going to add a few lines of boilerplate and run your server through `twistd`.

See the article [Running a Twisted Perspective Broker example with twistd](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/10/running-twisted-perspective-broker-example-twistd/) for a step-by-step walkthrough of how to do it.